# How to get CPU usage in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, load, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a main server and 4 computers connected. How can I learn which computer use how much CPU and disk.

I write code using Qt and C++.

Comment: I was about to say the same, bdonlan. Nine question and not one accepted answer. People get the impression that you don't appreciate their effort to help you.

Comment: I don't think Qt can do that. That's an issue of the platform you're working on. e.g. winapi when using windows.

Comment: I might be able to help, but could you edit your question to state what information you are needing?  For example on CPU: memory usage, cpu utilization, virtual memory usage, run process memory, etc.  Similar questions about disk.

Comment: First Thans a lot. I am new programmer and I try to learn this with writing code. I try to write a program which monitor main server and database server. How much disk is used, how much disk is free.
I did it. And I want to control cpu usage.I think run process memory is useful for my program. But you suggest any other feature I open it. Again thank a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Qt does not have an API for this.  You'll need to use the platforms native API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QProcess>

int main(void){
  setenv("LC_NUMERIC", "C",1);
  QProcess process;
  process.start("/usr/bin/uptime",{},QIODevice::ReadWrite);
  process.waitForFinished();

//Get results
  QString output = process.readAllStandardOutput();
  QString err = process.readAllStandardError();

//Get load portion
  QString loads=output.section("load average: ",1,1);
  QString load_lastmin=loads.section(" ",0,0);
  load_lastmin.remove(load_lastmin.size()-1,1);

//For debug
  qDebug() << "Output:" << output;
  qDebug() << "Error:" << err;
  qDebug() << "Loads:" << loads;
  qDebug() << "Load last min:" << load_lastmin;

  return 0;
}
```

Result example:

```
Output: " 10:04:33 up 3 days, 21:39,  1 user,  load average: 0.55, 0.71, 0.78\n"
Error: ""
Loads: "0.55, 0.71, 0.78\n"
Load last min: "0.55"
```